# "Eye for eye, and tooth for tooth" moment?

Tags: matthew, jesus, exodus

In Exodus 4:23 (NASB)

> So I said to you, ‘Let My son go so that he may serve Me’; but you have refused to let him go. Behold, I am going to kill your son, your firstborn.”’”

In Matthew 5:38-39 (NASB)

> 38 “You have heard that it was said, ‘Eye for eye, and tooth for tooth.’39 But I tell you, do not resist an evil person. If anyone slaps you on the right cheek, turn to them the other cheek also.

Is this Exodus passage an "eye for eye, and tooth for tooth" moment?

Comment: No, I do not think your edit makes any difference. You are interpreting two passages by connecting them in this way. It is still the expression of an opinion. More than that, it is a criticism of God, and you are using the words of Jesus Christ, God's Son, to make that criticism.

Comment: @NigelJ not necessarily critic but an observation of intended change in the behaviour

Comment: In that case, you imply that the 'behaviour' of God has 'changed'. _I am the Lord, I change not, therefore ye sons of Jacob are not consumed._

Comment: @NigelJ depends how one defines "change". If that was meant all along then it didn't really "change"

Comment: Righteousness never changes. God always does exactly what is according to his own being and nature. He is always consistent and never denies himself. The danger of what you are doing is to imply a difference in righteousness between God and his own Son.

Comment: @NigelJ no doubt there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two comments to make here about how God works in salvation history.

**1.  God is sovereign**

In His great wisdom and infinite understanding, God elects to do the things that He does and we must learn from His dealings with imperfect and incomplete understanding.

**2. Different Situations**

The situations in Ex 4:23 and Matt 5:38, 39 and quite different and not really comparable.  Matthew is discussing a relationship between two humans;  Exodus is discussing the relationship between a nation and God.  The two could not be much more different - almost opposite ends of the spectrum!

In the Bible we read that God must (because of our humanity) sometimes rube and chasten us in various ways.  In the case of Egypt, God sent nine chastening messages before the final, very severe one.  Note the way God deals with us at times:

- Ps 39:11 - When you rebuke and discipline anyone for their sin, you consume their wealth like a moth-- surely everyone is but a breath.
- Ps 38:1 - O LORD, do not rebuke me in Your anger or discipline me in Your wrath.
- Heb 12:5 - And you have forgotten the exhortation that addresses you as sons: “My son, do not take lightly the discipline of the Lord, and do not lose heart when He rebukes you.
- Rev 3:19 - Those I love, I rebuke and discipline. Therefore be earnest and repent.

Since God was rebuking and chastening Egypt, it proves that God loved Egypt and its people!!  However, they became very stubborn and needed very strong discipline.